# Group by child table in LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

I have students table and I have subjects tables I need to group students by subjects . I tried following which doesnt show s.StudentSubjects.SubjectName . How can I write group by with child table .

Students -> StudentID | Name
StudentSubjects -> SubjectID | StudentID | SubjectName

```
        var list = from s in students
                   group s by s.StudentSubjects.? into g
                   select new StudentSubjectsCounts
                   {
                       Name = g.Key,
                       Count = g.Count(),                           
                   };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you should query off of `StudentSubjects` instead of `Student`:

```
var list = from ss in studentSubjects
           group ss by s.SubjectName into g
           select new StudentSubjectsCounts
           {
               Name = g.Key,
               Count = g.Count(),                           
           };
```

Or, to start from a list of students:

```
var list = students.SelectMany(s => s.StudentSubjects)
                   .GroupBy(ss => ss.SubjectName)
                   .Select(g => new StudentSubjectsCounts
                       {
                           Name = g.Key,
                           Count = g.Count(),                           
                       });
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to group by the `StudentSubject` object itself

```
var list = from s in students
           group s by s.StudentSubjects into g
           select new StudentSubjectsCounts
           {
               Name = g.Key.SubjectName,
               Count = g.Count(),                           
           };
```

but if you don't want to, project the name using a `Select`

```
var list = from s in students
           group s by s.StudentSubjects.Select(ss => ss.SubjectName) into g
           select new StudentSubjectsCounts
           {
               Name = g.Key,
               Count = g.Count(),                           
           };
```

Comment: yes there are some reasons I need to use second option you suggested , but how "g" comes in to place ?

Comment: he forgot to add `into g` on the end of the `group` lines.